# What's wrong with this gmail contact importer script for Drupal?

Tags: drupal, open-source, gmail, import-contacts

Drupal has a gmail contact importer module that's been oh-so-close to working for about 7 months now.  I don't have the chops to debug the problem, the maintainer vanished, and I think this is an important piece to have working.  So I turn to StackOverflow for help.

The Problem: When you fill in your credentials and tell the script to bring back your contacts, by default it pulls in 25.  That works fine.

When you tell it to look for more contacts by changing the URL you're querying from this:

```
http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin
```

to this:

```
http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?max-results=1000
```

You get the following fatal error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `getAttribute()` on a non-object in `path/to/site/sites/all/modules/dcl_importer/scripts/importGData.class.php` on line 97

Here's the script:

```
class GDataMailer {
    static $url_ClientLogin = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';
    static $url_Feed = 'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?max-results=65535';

    function newCurlSession($URL, $auth = null) {
        $curl = curl_init();

        $opts = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $URL,
            CURLOPT_REFERER => '',
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        );
        if (null != $auth) {
            $opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = array(
               'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='.$auth,
            );
        }
        curl_setopt_array($curl, $opts);
        return $curl;
    }

    function useCurlForPost($curl, $params) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        return $curl;
    }

    function getAuthToken($login, $password) {
        $curl = $this->useCurlForPost($this->newCurlSession(self::$url_ClientLogin), array(
           'accountType' => 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE',
           'Email' => $login,
           'Passwd' => $password,
           'service' => 'cp',
           'source' => 'Drupal-Contact-Importer',
        ));
        $resp = curl_exec($curl);

        // Look for the important stuff:
        preg_match_all('/Auth=([^\s]*)/si', $resp, $matches);
        if (isset($matches[1][0])) {
            return $matches[1][0];
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }

    function getAddressbook($login, $password) {
        // check if username and password was given:
        if ((isset($login) && trim($login)=="") || (isset($password) && trim($password)==""))
        {
            $args = func_get_args();
            drupal_set_message('Incorrect login information given: '.print_r($args, true), 'error');
            return false;
        }

        // Get the GData auth token:
        $auth = $this->getAuthToken($login, $password);
        if (false === $auth) {
            drupal_set_message('Login failed', 'error');
            return false;
        }        

        $curl = $this->newCurlSession(self::$url_Feed, $auth);
        $data = curl_exec($curl);

        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadXML($data);
        $path = new DOMXPath($doc);
        $path->registerNamespace('a', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
        $path->registerNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
        $nodes = $path->query('//a:entry');
        $num = $nodes->length;

        $contacts = array();
        for ($x = 0; $x < $num; $x++) {
            $entry = $nodes->item($x);
            $tnodes = $path->query('a:title', $entry);
            $nnode = $tnodes->item(0);
            $name = $nnode->textContent;
            $enodes = $path->query('gd:email', $entry);
            $mnode = $enodes->item(0);
            $email = $mnode->getAttribute('address');
            // NOTE: Keep in mind that $mnode->getAttribute('rel') tells you what kind of email it is.
            // NOTE: Also remember that there can be multiple emails per entry!
            if (empty($name)) {
                $contacts[] = $email;
            } else {
                $contacts[$name] = $email;
            }
        }        

        return $contacts;
    }
}
```

Line 97 is that `$email = $mnode->getAttribute('address');` line near the end.

What can I change here to not get that error anymore and get this working for the Drupal community?  I want to pull in all of a person's contact list, not just 25.  I figure if I sent the number high enough, it'll be close enough to get by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without testing it directly, I would try replacing lines 96 - 104 with this:

```
$mnode = $enodes->item(0);
if (isset($mnode) && is_object($mnode)) {
    $email = $mnode->getAttribute('address');
    // NOTE: Keep in mind that $mnode->getAttribute('rel') tells you what kind of email it is.
    // NOTE: Also remember that there can be multiple emails per entry!
    if (!empty($email)) {
        if (empty($name)) {
            $contacts[] = $email;
        } else {
            $contacts[$name] = $email;
        }
    }
}
```

gd:email is an optional element according to the [Google Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/elements.html#gdEmail). It's optional in Gmail's implementation too. The module you're using assumes it exists and fails when it doesn't.

Multiple e-mail addresses per contact remain unhandled, as per the NOTE: comment.